# Risk in keep using OpenUDID pasteboards approach instead of identifierForVendor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, udid

Even with the latest iOS6's `identifierForVendor`, what I found is when user deleted the app and the value will get reset.

Unlike the traditional OpenUDID pasteboards' approach, it keep in the pasteboards and can re-use them.

I can't see if Apple is going to ban the pasteboards, so should we keep using OpenUDID in the `pasteboards` mode?

(Also `pasteboards` is being widely supported)

Comment: What "pasteboards"? Do you mean the `UIPasteboard` class?

Comment: Yes, see: https://github.com/ylechelle/OpenUDID/blob/master/OpenUDID.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two parts to my answers:

1. identifierForVendor is really not a good equivalent for UDID or OpenUDID. You should look into the new Framework called AdSupport (formerly known as identifierForAdvertising). There is a unique identifier there that basically fulfills the unique identifier + preserved + cross apps, with two caveats: A/ the user may "opt-out" from the preferences by toggling a flag (it's actually a soft flag) B/ the user may reset the identifier in the settings...
2. OpenUDID will be updated this week or next with iOS 6 compliant code.

All in all, OpenUDID is great for the transition between iOS 5 and iOS 6. Overtime, iOS 6 native APIs will be enough to cover your needs.

Comment: The problem with `identifierForAdvertising`, user can choose to opt out, that is the problem...

Comment: I think that is a very good option to offer to your users: don't track them if they don't want.

Comment: @Ryan it is just a soft flag, as said by Yann

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching around and this industry changes every day. From what I see OpenUDID is not worth the risk as of June 2013 since:

1. According to http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/ as of May 29th 2013 88.6% of iOS users use iOS 6.x
2. The Advertiser ID does the same thing but as stated above has a soft off mode (asks you not to use it) which is fair enough. You may add in your agreement that you do track users in the free version of your app even when the phone is in do not track mode (apps are not really free)